# Adding odd numbers in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to find the sum of all odd numbers within a given range but I cannot figure out how to specify which numbers are odd. My professor said to use "for num in numbers" to access the elements in the range. This is what I have so far.

```
numbers = range(0, 10)

def addOddNumbers(numbers):
    for num in numbers:
        if num % 2 == 1:
            return sum
        print sum(numbers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    addOddNumbers(numbers)
```

Answer (score 3):

You were nearly there; using `num % 2` is the correct method to test for odd and even numbers.

`return` exits a function the moment it is executed. Your function returns when the first odd number is encountered.

Don't use `sum()` if you use a loop, just add the numbers directly:

```
def addOddNumbers(numbers):
    total = 0
    for num in numbers:
        if num % 2 == 1:
            total += num
    print total
```

You *could* first build a list of odd numbers for `sum()`:

```
def addOddNumbers(numbers):
    odd = []
    for num in numbers:
        if num % 2 == 1:
            odd.append(num)
    print sum(odd)
```

For `sum()`, you can use a generator expression:

```
def addOddNumbers(numbers):
    print sum(num for num in numbers if num % 2 == 1)
```

Comment: When you are setting total = 0 what exactly is that doing? What does the total += num do?

Comment: @user3081186: You need to have *a* number in `total` to be able to add more values to it. For a sum, starting with `0` is a good start.

Comment: total += num just adds num to the total and stores it back into total.

Comment: @user3081186: The `total += num` line adds `num` to the `total` value, storing it back in `total`. For numbers, `total += num` is the same `total = total + num`, but shorter.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest a small tweak to Martijn Pieter's excellent answer?

To make your method more flexible, try incorporating range into the method. It will make your method able to sum the odd values in any list. Also, I switched up your method signature so that it conforms to the Python Style Guide [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), just being picky here:)

```
def add_odd_numbers(max_list_value):
    numbers = range(0, max_list_value)
    total = 0
    for num in numbers:
        if num % 2 == 1:
            total += num
    return total

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print add_odd_numbers(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
def addOddNumbers(numbers):
    return sum(num for num in numbers if num % 2 == 1) # or use print instead of return
```

To print it if you use return, you would precede the function call with the print statement:

```
print addOddNumbers(numbers)
```

your statement `return sum` just returns the `sum` function(nothing else) and exits the `addOddNumbers` function.

`print sum(numbers)` actually just prints the sum of EVERY number in numbers:

you for loop if would need a variable to keep track of your total:

```
total = 0
for n in numbers:
    if n % 2 == 1:
        total += n # total accumulates the sum of all odd numbers then you can return or print it
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make a quick comment in the form of an answer. If you wanted to make a list of all the odd number in a between 0 and 10, the end points don't matter. If the list was from 0 to 11 then the end point matters. Just remember that `range(0,11) = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and won't include 11.

---

Now to explain the generator that is being used. To make to list using `numbers` as defined by you, you could do this.

```
odds = []
for num in numbers:
    if num % 2 == 1:
        odds.append(num)
```

This would give you `odds = [1,3,5,7,9]`. Python has something call list comprehension that make it really easy to do things like this. The above can be easily written like this

```
odds = [num for num in number if num % 2 == 1]
```

and since you want the sum off all the numbers in the list and the `sum` function takes list, the answer is just

```
sum([num for num in number if num % 2 == 1])
```

Note that most of the answer don't have brackets. This is because without it it becomes a generator.

```
odds = (num for num in number if num % 2 == )
print odds  #--> <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f9d220669b0>
odds.next() # 1
odds.next() # 3
...
```

Since `sum` takes these as well and generator are faster and less memory intensive than list that is why the best answer is

```
sum(num for num in numbers if num % 2 == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `sum(range(1,end_number,2)` will work well, and easy,.

Answer (score -2):

The modulo operator "%" is what you want, and have used.  However, modulo returns the remainder, so the remainder of an even number divided by 2 is 0.

So, you want to change:

```
if num % 2 == 1:
```

to

```
if num % 2 == 0:
```